# Add file to X: volume in WinPE

Tags: winpe

I have an existing WinPE USB flash drive. When I boot from the drive I have a command prompt at this location:

```
X:\Windows\System32
```

I want to add a text file to this location. This is to make it easier to find for others who will use this USB key.

There are other tools already on this WinPE disk; I don't want to start over and recreate it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do this?

You can’t.

> I want to add a text file to this location. This is to make it easier to find for others who will use this USB key.
>
> There are other tools already on this WinPE disk; I don't want to start over and recreate it.

If you want a text file at that location, it must be added to the WinPE image itself.  Creation of a file while you have already accessed the WinPE environment and placed it into system  memory doesn’t modify the image itself.

You will have to recreate the WinPE image and add the file.

Comment: How you modify the image is well documented but outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Bummer. It's one step forward, two steps back, then :(

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - This isn't a new limitation of .wim files, which is the file type of WinPE images, you can only mount .wim files in read-only mode.

Answer (score 2):

.WIM files can be mounted as read-only, but DISM as well as GUI Tools like PowerISO allow you to mount the image, modify, and write-back those changes.
DISM, PowerISO mount the folder/files to a temp directory.
You can then add, remove, edit files folders, add programs, etc... then commit he changes to the wim file.
In the case of a bootable WinPE or another utility based on WinPE, there is a sources folder with the wim file. The actual wim file as earlier stated is what is actually loaded into a RAM Disk and is what you see at the program you are using.

See below example. I started with Killdisk WinPE, but added a menu for McAfee, PENetwork, and more mostly using PowerISO.
After myself messing with building lots of PE boot disks, I would buy killdisk boot disk, and then you can modify the menus for your own appps. Lsoft already did alot of work on the graphics, menus, etc... and made life wit WinPE disk building alot easier scaffolding of their boot disk.
[image]